# GIS database table setup with multiple columns or FK

Tags: postgresql, database-design, table, postgis

I am trying to design a environmental GIS table setup in a geospatial database. The workflow process is to create

1. a Permit To Disturb (PTD Table)
2. and for each PTD there will be a point, line and polygon table that defines the PTD area details and status
3. Next when its approved disturbance can be done and again 3 separate tables for point line and polygon will have the same columns as the PTD tables
4. once disturbance has been completed, rehab has to be done, this can be done on the whole area or part of it over separate time frames.

I have attached a figure showing the tables, my question is what would be the most optimum setup since all 3 tables share a lot of columns but obviously for different information. I guess this could be simplified a bit by using alphanumerical id's on the tables to prevent identical id in the FK table. That would reduce the FK down to 3, or maybe even 1.

Do I create a details table and a status table that uses foreign keys to each of the other groups of tables. and assign some logic around allowing nulls etc. or should i just put all the columns in each table?

Any ideas welcome on this problem, it will go into a PostgreSQL PostGIS database if that helps?

[image: Figure showing tables]

Comment: If the tables are queries together, consider using a single table. If the semantics of the data are different, and the data are used in different ways, different tables may be better.

Comment: Should you be posting this on [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: its really a database setup question, i am just seeking some ideas around how other people might setup this scenario. i tried with different tables but it would be come very complex very quickly when the data types stores are really the same, just different for each table.